# Trying to deploy an Angular application to Heroku

Tags: angular, heroku

I try to deploy an Angular application to Heroku, but I keep getting this error:

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command...

Answer (score 3):

You need to debug in heroku logs. Try this command `heroku logs --tail --app your_app_name` and tell us what error you are getting.

Comment: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=angualr-app-deploy.herokuapp.com request_id=0e5c73ac-ba62-43ea-9567-ae21d7bbb0a2 fwd="92.99.193.214" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: @marc_s any chance